# sbcl vs clisp: USOCKET:TIMEOUT-ERROR. Do the two implementations access USOCKET differently?

Tags: amazon-s3, lisp, common-lisp

I have a script that uses quicklisp to load zs3 for accessing Amazon's S3.

When I run the script with clisp, when `(zs3:bucket-exists-p "Test")` is run, USOCKET:TIMEOUT-ERROR occurs.

However, when I run it with sbcl, it runs properly.

Do they access usocket differently?

What are the pros and cons of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usocket is a compatibility layer which hides the underlying socket API of each Lisp implementation. There is bound to be an impedance mismatch in some cases, but for the most part it should just work.

I suspect zs3 is not often used with CLISP (or perhaps not at all!), and you're seeing the result of that. On the other hand one can generally expect libraries to be well-tested under SBCL since that is the most popular implementation.

Note also that threads are still experimental in CLISP; they are not enabled by default. The fact that sockets are often mixed with threads only decreases the relative use of CLISP + usocket.